# Google play services admob - super.onAdLoaded(), super.onAdFailedToLoad(...)

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services, interstitial

Quick question:

In the context of an Android activity,

In an `adListenner`, when overriding `onAdLoaded(){}` and `onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode){}`, should `super.onAdLoaded()` and `super.onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)` be called in the overriden methods?

If so, should the call be made at the beginning or end of the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdListener is an interface, there is no super class method to call.

And in any, generally in Java, Adapters (abstract Listener implementations provided for convenience)  contain no implementation in the adapter. The methods are just there so that you  don't need to implement those methods that you aren't using.

Answer (score 2):

A very good question, wondering that myself - that is generally good practice, if you want to preserve the logic from the parent class. In this case it won't make a difference.

com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener is actually an abstract class with empty methods - I believe the listener used to be an interface, which forced you to implement all methods hence the change to an abstract class.

You can take a Java decompiler like say JD-GUI and look at the code yourself (google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar):

```
package com.google.android.gms.ads;

public abstract class AdListener
{
  public void onAdClosed() {}  
  public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {}  
  public void onAdLeftApplication() {}  
  public void onAdOpened() {}  
  public void onAdLoaded() {}
}
```